# nsTemplateKey ignored in NativeScript ListView

Tags: listview, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm attempting to use two templates in a ListView, but the ListView always picks the first template. The callback function is returning the correct value for the template key to no effect.

Markup:

```
<ListView row="0" [items]="eventRoll.people" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)"
  [itemTemplateSelector]="templateSelector">
  <template nsTemplateKey="absent" let-item="item">
    <Label  style="background-color:lightblue" [text]="item.isAccounted ? 'here' : 'absent'"></Label>
  </template>
  <template nsTemplateKey="here" let-item="item">
    <Label  style="background-color:lightgreen" [text]="item.isAccounted ? 'here' : 'absent'"></Label>
  </template>
</ListView>
```

TypeScript:

```
public templateSelector = (item: Person, index: number, items: any) => {
  let key = item.isAccounted ? "here" : "absent";
  return key;
}
```

I've simplified the markup, so that the only difference is the background color. Whichever template is first is being used regardless of the nsTemplateKey.

What am I missing? Why aren't the templates being used according to the key?

Comment: If this is Angular 4 then `template` should be `ng-template`. I don't see anything else obvious.

Comment: Thanks @EddyVerbruggen! What fixed it was updating the framework and using ng-template like you mentioned!